# VBA to Select last row in print layout, then paste value in it and loop over a selected number of sheets (the bottom line is a varible.)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a number of sheets that all need the same three rows pasted in at the end of the document, the row number for the document end is different on every sheet.

The sheets named 2-22, will need to be activated, un protected, the rows pasted at the end then re protected and looped to do the same for the next sheet.

See below for code, as you will see there are gaps as I cant seem to find away to select the correct row and loop it for certain sheets not every sheet.

```
Dim i As Worksheet
For Each i In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
i.Activate

activesheet.unprotect password:="Password"

selection.paste

activesheet.protect password:="Password"
Next i
```

Comment: So are you asking how to find the last row?

Comment: `lLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: @danieltakeshi from the link I have worked out how to do the last row, how do I only apply this to sheets renamed from 2-20?

Comment: To apply your code only to sheets with a particular number in their name you could do something like `If IsNumeric(i.Name) Then` and then `If CInt(i.Name) >= 2 And CInt(i.Name) <= 20 Then`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To loop through the Sheets and get the last Row from column "A", use this code as Sample, for Sheets 2-22, using the name of those Sheets and NOT index:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, lLastRow As Long

For i = 2 To 22 'From 2 to 22 named
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(CStr(i))
    lLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Debug.Print ws.Name & " " & ws.Cells(lLastRow, 1).Address
Next i
```

If you want to get the last row from all Sheets from the Workbook or using the index number, the pro of using the index number is that the Sheet name can vary.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, lLastRow As Long

For i = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count 'For all Sheets or For i = 2 To 22 to end on 22
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i)
    lLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Debug.Print ws.Name & " " & ws.Cells(lLastRow, 1).Address
Next i
```

So to paste something, you would paste on the next row, so use: `lLastRow+1`

Answer (score 0):

We suppose that the rows you want to copy are in the sheet1(`Sheet1.Rows("1:3")`),

run `Sub CallAll`

( i have used this reference: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm)

```
Option Explicit


Sub CallAll()

copy_rows
protect_unprotect

End Sub



Sub copy_rows()

    Sheet1.Rows("1:3").Select
    Selection.Copy

End Sub

Sub protect_unprotect()

Dim i As Worksheet


For Each i In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
  If i.ProtectContents = True Then
  i.Unprotect Password:="Password"
  copy_rows
  End If
Next


For Each i In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

i.Activate
Call LastRow_Example(i)

Next


For Each i In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

If i.ProtectContents = False Then

i.Protect Password:="Password"

End If

Next

End Sub


Sub LastRow_Example(sh As Worksheet)

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range


    ' Use all cells on the sheet
    Set rng = sh.Cells


    ' Find the last row
    LastRow = Last(1, rng)

    ' After the last row with data change the value of the cell in Column A



    rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub

Function Last(choice As Long, rng As Range)

    Dim lrw As Long
    Dim lcol As Long

    Select Case choice

    Case 1:
        On Error Resume Next
        Last = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0

    Case 2:
        On Error Resume Next
        Last = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0

    Case 3:
        On Error Resume Next
        lrw = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                       After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                       Lookat:=xlPart, _
                       LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                       SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                       MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0

        On Error Resume Next
        lcol = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0

        On Error Resume Next
        Last = rng.Parent.Cells(lrw, lcol).Address(False, False)
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            Last = rng.Cells(1).Address(False, False)
            Err.Clear
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

    End Select
End Function
```